# Cookie entre controllers

Tags: zend, cookies, controller

Criei o seguinte cookie no controller Localidade:

```
$cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('localidade_id', $localidade->getIdentificador(), time() + 3600);
```

Contudo, ao tentar acessá-lo no controller Contato:

```
 $getcookie = $request->getCookie();
 $getcookie->offsetGet('localidade_id');
```

o retorno é NULL. Mas se o acesso for feito no controller Localidade, eu tenho um valor válido.

É a primeira vez uso cookies com ZF2, então não sei se tem alguma coisa errada.
Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema é o `path` (quarto parâmetro). Por padrão, o cookie é setado no diretório atual: `/localidade`. Teria que setar ele para o domínio inteiro: `/`, assim:

```
$cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('localidade_id', $localidade->getIdentificador(), time() + 3600, '/');
```

Comment: Obrigada. Era esse o problema